# Convert value to double with specific provider in C#

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, csv, accord.net

I need to parse CSV file, get specific columns, and convert values to double. My code below works fine if all values can be converted to double :). But how should I update the code if value will be equal "TRUE"/"FALSE" ?

**Code:**

```
dt = GetDataTableFromCsv("my_csv.csv");
// Gets the column of the dependent/indepent variable
// I need structure double [][]
var input = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => independentNames.Where(i => dt.Columns.Contains(i)).Select(c => Convert.ToDouble(r.Field<object>(c), provider(???))).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

**Example of CSV:**

> Rank,  Value, TV,  IS_NEW, IS_HOME, RATINGS, ...
>
> "1", "0.5", "CNN", "TRUE", "FALSE", "888.77" ....

- "TV" should be ignored, it's not in `independentNames`
- "TRUE"/"FALSE" => 1.0/0.0

Comment: What `double` value does `TRUE` represent?  What about `TV`?  Why not create a data structure that has double, string, and boolean fields?

Comment: Updated description, thank you!

Comment: Seems like what you're trying to do could be done much easier, but it's hard to tell with so little code posted.  Why not create a custom class that can handle all columns from the CSV and then you can use them however you like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need to do is wrap `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` to `1.0` and `0.0`, separate the logic to your own method and call it instead of `Convert.ToDouble`.

You will still need to handle invalid inputs, either in this method or at a higher scope.

```
double AsDouble(string input)
{
    switch (input)
    {
        case "TRUE": return 1.0;
        case "FALSE": return 0.0;

        //any other special cases

        default: return Convert.ToDouble(input); //may still throw!
    }
}
```